# how to count word count in innertext of tag and spilt this according count word with tag

Tags: php, regex

**i have a problem like as:**

```
$str="i am a <b>software</b> <span style=\"color:red;\">engineer.</span>  i work at a company.";  //here, total word 10 (according inner text)
```

and i want to get only 5 word with tag like as:
**output:**

```
$output="i am a <b>software</b> <span style=\"color:red;\">engineer.</span>";  // 5 word
```

how it is possible? please help me.. thanks.

i have word counter function:

```
function word( $str, $wordCount = 10 ) {
        return implode( 
        '', 
        array_slice( 
        preg_split(
        '/([\s,\.;\?\!]+)/', 
        $str, 
        $wordCount*2+1, 
        PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
        ),
        0,
        $wordCount*2-1
        )
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More precise solution

```
<?php
$input = 'i am a <b>software</b> <span style=\"color:red;\">engineer. And </span> i work at a company.';

var_dump(customParse($input, 5));
var_dump(customParse($input, 4));
var_dump(customParse($input, 3));

$input = 'i am a <b>software</b> <foo style=\"color:red;\">engineer. And </foo> i work at a company.';

var_dump(customParse($input, 5));

function customParse($input, $limit) {
    $pattern = '#(
    \s*
    (?: <(\w+) [^>]* >)*
    [a-z.-]+
    (</[^>]*>)*
    )#x';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches);
    $result = '';
    for ($nbMatch = 0; $nbMatch < $limit; $nbMatch++) {
        $capturedText = $matches[0][$nbMatch];
        $openTag = $matches[2][$nbMatch];
        $closeTag = $matches[3][$nbMatch];

        $result .= $capturedText;

        if ($openTag && !$closeTag) {
            $result .= '</' . $openTag . '>';
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: My pleasure :)
Again, you must adpat the ```[a-z.-]+``` to match what is really acceptable as a "word" for you.

Comment: i can do that, i have a some knowledge of regex. but this case was advance label for me. thanks (can i get your fb id?)

Comment: StackOverflow is my facebook ;)

Comment: thanks for help me. and a little problem is created for case single tag like as:`<br/> , <hr/> <img/>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, but you must adapt it to fit what are allowed characters in a word :

```
<?php
$input = 'i am a <b>software</b> <span style=\"color:red;\">engineer.</span>  i work at a company.';
$pattern = '#((?: \s* (<[^>]*>)* [a-z.-]+ (</[^>]*>)* ){0,5}).*#x';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $input);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. but is it possible? in case `$in="i am a <b>software</b> <span style=\"color:red;\">engineer. And </span>  i work at a company."`  `$out="i am a <b>software</b> <span style=\"color:red;\">engineer.</span>"`  word count 5 and added with end tag `</span>`

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible. You can use `preg_match_all` like this :

```
<?php
$input = 'i am a <b>software</b> <span style=\"color:red;\">engineer. And </span> i work at a company.';
$pattern = '#(
\s*
(<[^>]*>)*
[a-z.-]+
(</[^>]*>)*
)#x';
preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

And then, for each match, you test if $matches[2][index] is not empty and $matches[3][index] is empty to add the closing tag.
But i think it's not complete and prone to errors. You probably will have to modify it to run with all possibilities.

Comment: please give me clear answer like as your first answer. your first answer is very fine.. i think have to use `match sub pattern`. but i can't understand   `match sub pattern`. please modified the first answer. i hope that will work